# Error on "cargo run --example address" (Chrysalis Documentation - Rust)

Tags: documentation, chrysalis

I downloaded the github repository [iotaledger/iota.rs](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs) to my PC and run

```
cargo run --example address
```

according to the instructions on the [IOTA Client Library](https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/libraries/rust/examples.html) website and the following error occured :

[image: error]

The error refers to this line of code:

```
   let seed = Seed::from_bytes(&hex::decode(env::var("NONSECURE_USE_OF_DEVELOPMENT_SEED_1").unwrap()).unwrap());
```

I also tried to manipulate the code a little bit to resolve the error with replacing

```
NONSECURE_USE_OF_DEVELOPMENT_SEED_1
```

with the actual seed value defined in `.env.example`

```
256a818b2aac458941f7274985a410e57fb750f3a3a67969ece5bd9ae7eef5b2
```

which successfully compiled, but when I run the `.exe` the same error occurs:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NotPresent', examples\address.rs:26:94
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I am new to Rust (started few days ago because of IOTA) so maybe there is a lack of basic Rust understanding. What also confuses me a little bit is the `.env.example` file. How is the `.env.example` file linked to the `adress.rs` file?

Can someone please help me to resolve the error?

Comment: does it help when you rename the `.env.example` file to `.env`. Some Rust programs read an `.env` file at startup to populate environment variables...

Comment: It worked, Thank you!